# Auto switch input source to English when entering Spotlight, typing URL in Safari, etc

Tags: macos, spotlight, language, url

I don't have files with non-english names, and don't type non-latin URL's, so question is how to auto switch system input source in these occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Using KeyRemap4MacBook, you could save something like this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test1</name>
<identifier>test1</identifier>
<only>SAFARI</only>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::L, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTMODE_ENGLISH</autogen>
</item>
<item>
<name>test2</name>
<identifier>test2</identifier>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::SPACE, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTMODE_ENGLISH</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

It only works with those two shortcuts and it doesn't change the input source back later though. See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Alfred has an option to always switch to a specific input source:

[image]